# Display domain name instead of IP when using Nginx + Gunicorn + Django

Tags: nginx, ip, django, domain-name

I am building a server on Ubuntu using Nginx + Gunicorn + Django.

I have a domain name registered with godaddy that redirects to the IP of the server. The Nginx configuration looks like this:

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name mydomainname.com www.mydomainname.com localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/my/socket.sock;
        }
    }
```

When I type the domain name in the browser, I get correctly redirected to the server. However, the url in the browser now displays the IP instead of the domain name.

How can I make the server display the domain name instead of the IP?

(Godaddy provides an option to do this by using forward masking, but I have been advised not to use this, and the browser complains about cross-origin problems anyway when I try this approach.)

I'm not even sure if I need to change something in Nginx or Gunicorn or Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, and it had nothing to do with Nginx's configuration. I was looking in the entirely wrong place.

I mistakenly set up a URL forwarding command at the website where I bought my domain name. I should have set up a type 'A' DNS record instead. I didn't know those were two different things and was unlucky enough to find the URL forwarding feature before finding the DNS records.

Answer (score 0):

The [sample configuration](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html) suggests that you also need to pass the `Host:` header upstream. For example, ripped out of that same configuration:

```
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
      # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
      proxy_redirect off;
```

Comment: I tried it, but doing this did not change the browser's behavior. (to be clear, I added 'proxy_set_header Host $http_host;' to the location block)

Comment: Check your application, then, and make sure it isn't sending a redirect.

Comment: So you are saying Nginx should work the way it is? By application, do you mean Gunicorn or Django? How do I check if it's sending a redirect?

Comment: gunicorn just answers HTTP requests and passes them on to your Django app. There's nothing to look at there.